# How can I make a left side popup box when hovering element in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a text content popup box appear when mouse hovers some HTML element?

I need the overlay to fit its content, because the way it is now is cropping the text, it's getting the height of the HTML element and not the height of its content.

It only slides left, but that's okay with me. I am going to place the html element to the right of the page later on, but I need to be able to set a margin from the starting point of the popup, because it slides just next the HTML element, I'd like some space between.

This is what I have got so far:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay:hover {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  right: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  My Text
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: There is no room to the left of "My Text", so what is your expected result?

Comment: I simplified the code a little bit, but as I said it will be placed in the right side of a page, so that's not my worry, I only need to fit its content and to add some space between the html element and the popup. I am open to other components, I was working in this one.

Comment: So just replace `right: 100%;` with `left: 100%;`. Isn't that the expected result?

Comment: @connexo Due to the transform effect, that probably will trigger a buggy comeback, as the effect applied is on hovering, when the mouse goes off the area, it'll probably get the effect back coming from the left side of the text, looking weirdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if that's what you're wondering to happen :

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.link .tip {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  right: 105%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.link:hover .tip {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="link">Hover me now !
    <span class="tip">
      Some few text here<br><br>
      Let's try something else<br><br>
      And adding more info here too<br><br>
      And even a bit more here also
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for making it in a visible way, the idea here is add lots of text into that overlay, but it doesn't grow up in height, it crops content, it is taking the "My Text" height as max height. And the other thing is, I'd like to make the sliding a little bit far from "My Text" just a little space, not to be so glued together.

Comment: @Felipe Edited the code, see if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, you solved the problem of margin, but my main need is to be able to add text content to the overlay, the overlay doesn't fit it's content. Try adding a new line to Hello World , put a <br> and then more text, it gets weird.

Comment: @Felipe Edited the whole code so I could manage coding it in my own way, see if that helps you now